# Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet'

Tags: c#

I try to read a excel file with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.
But the last line int the following code give me an error.
How do i get the Sheets ?

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets["Liste"];
```

> 1. Error (CS0266): Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet'. An explicit conversion
>      exists (are you missing a cast?) (line 60)

Any tip is welcome

Comment: "*An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*"

Comment: nobody never reads exception messages

Comment: What is the return type of `Workbook.Sheets[string]`? `object` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Excel._Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets["Liste"];
```

Comment: or `xlWorkbook.Sheets["Liste"] as Excel._Worksheet`